# Autocomplete or create new object for model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement something similar to the SO/Gmail Tag system: "Try to find a matching tag or create a new".

I have two simple classes:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `CategoryController` implements a `AutoCompleteCategory`-method that returns a Json list of all available categories:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCategory(string term)
{
    var result = categoryRepository.All.Where(category=> category.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Distinct();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I already have a jquery-Script that sends the request to the method and displays the matches.

**Now to my problem:**

What do I need to use in the `_CreateOrEdit`-View to map this edit-field to my model? It would represent my Category, but usually I bind it to CategoryId, which is a simple key, don't I?

And if the edit field contains a unknown category, how can I create it and bind it to my model?

Comment: Little lost,   What edit field?

Comment: Well, the field that is uses to enter the category.